# iPhone View-Based Application Doesn't Have Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone tab bar controller and core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365792/iphone-tab-bar-controller-and-core-data)

In Xcode,

I'd like to go File -> New Project -> and pick View Based Application. But it doesn't have the "Use core data for storage" (like some of the other projects). So I can't assign a core data to it.

I'd like to know if this is an issue, and what's the best route to take for what I'm trying to do? (Which is build a core data based app ... but I was hoping to do it with the view-based since that has alot of things written for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops I asked something that was already there, my bad

[iphone tab bar controller and core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365792/iphone-tab-bar-controller-and-core-data)

Answer (score 5):

You can always add in the existing Core Data framework, and then set it up yourself. You could generate a project that uses Core Data, and copy and paste out of there what you need (which is essentially (1) setting up the managed object model, (2) setting up the persistent store coordinator, and (3) setting up the managed object context).