# How Do I Add CoreData to a Tab Bar Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I just updated to Xcode 4.01 or 4.1 (forgot) and I don't see the option to create an App and use Core Data.  Before, I when I chose a template from the template chooser, the option would be there.  It isn't now.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode 4 the option "Use Core Data" is only available in the following iOS templates:

- Navigation-based Application
- Split View-based Application
- Utility Application
- Window-based Application

Comment: Ok, now I see it there.  I thought it was on all options.  I want to use a tab based app.  Why isn't it available for that?

Comment: Read this post. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1365792/261305 which basically seems to ask the same question as you do.

Comment: You can just copy and paste over the Core Data related properties and methods from one of the other templates. The Core Data stack is identical in all the templates. It is, however, a weird oversight on Apple's part.